# How to write a swift function that takes tuples as argument?

Tags: sorting, dictionary, tuples, swift2

Using Swift 2, I have a dictionary of type [String:String]. Now I want to use the sort method which requires a routine as follows:

```
mydict.sort(isOrderedBefore: ((String, String), (String, String)) -> Bool)
```

I assume the two arguments of type (String, String) could be elements of my dictionary. Hence I need two things:

1. A sort-routine with the requested type that compares the first elements of the two tuples it got as arguments. How do I write this function? I tried the version shown below and others. All produced errors.

   ```
   fun mysort( (k1,v1):(String,String), (k2,v2):(String,String)) -> Bool {
   return k1 > k2
   ```

   }
2. How does the compiler know it has to extract two distinct elements from mydict? The call of the sort routine would be:

   ```
   mydict.sort(mysort)
   ```

Looks fairly simple, but.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let dict = [1:"beta",2:"cecil",3:"alfa"]

let sorted: Array<(Int,String)> = dict.sort { $0.1 < $1.1 } // sorted is an Array<(Int,String)>
print(dict)
// [2: "cecil", 3: "alfa", 1: "beta"]

sorted.forEach { (pair) -> () in
    print(pair.0,pair.1)
}
/*
3 alfa
1 beta
2 cecil
*/

let sortingClosureDescendingByVale = { (pair1:( Int, String), pair2:(Int, String)) -> Bool in
    pair2.1 < pair1.1
}

let sortedWithClosure = dict.sort(sortingClosureDescendingByVale)
print(sortedWithClosure) // as array of tuple [(2, "cecil"), (1, "beta"), (3, "alfa")]

sortedWithClosure.forEach { (pair) -> () in
    print(pair.0,pair.1)
}
/*
2 cecil
1 beta
3 alfa
*/
```

or if you prefer

```
let sortingClosureDescendingByVale = { (pair1:(key:Int, value:String), pair2:(key:Int, value:String)) -> Bool in
    pair2.value < pair1.value
}
```

second question: you can ask the same, about sorting Array ...